GSM antenna matching issue
I have developed a PCB which uses a SIM800C module for communication. I am using an external antenna designed for GSM frequencies. According to the accumulated knowledge and hardware design guide of SIM800C, I prepared the PCB for placing of a PI matching network. The trace from SIM800C ANT port to the IPEX connect is as short as was possible with rounded bends and is impedance matched to 50 ohms - it is traced as a coplanar waveguide with width 0.8mm, distance to reference plane 1.3104 mm and gap to coplanar plane 0.16 mm for a frequency of 1350 MHz (because GSM operates in frequency range 876-915/921-960 MHz and 1710-1785/1805-1880 MHz the transmission line was tuned to a the middle frequency of both these ranges.
For measuring using a VNA a switch connector MM8130-2600RA2 together with probe
MXHS83QE3000 are used.
Without any matching componenets (only a 0 ohm resistor in place of R101), the VNA shows relativly good results (see pic), but it can be improved. Howver, when I place the recommded componenets (calculated by VNA and then verified in only tool), the measured results are completely differnet than what is expected.
The VNA is correctly calibrated with the probe MXHS83QE3000 for open, short and load.
The used capacitors and inductors are from the set L603DC and S603TS
I tried different cominbations, values, shut and series for inductors and capacitors, smaller frequency range and always the measured results were totally different than expected based on the online tools (for example Smith chart) - it is expected that due to parastic effects the measured results will be a bit different, but in this case the measurement are completely off.
I checked all materials and videos online I could find on matching, but did not find a mention of such issues. Does anyone have any idea what could the root cause be and how I can fix this problem? Thanks!
I am attaching picutres of the layout, including the PCB physical stackup.
Best regards
Jan





